# need to retain values in text boxes after submit button on click if found error

Tags: php, html, submit

heartily regards from me
I need to retain values in text boxes after submit button on click if found error.
basically the thing I want, if user left any fields blank and press save button then error message pop up and without refreshing the page it takes back the user to the form where he just have to fill the fields that were left blank... below is my code

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="">
Enter Name  :   <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
Enter Password  :   <input type="password" name="pass" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
</form>
</html>
php code
<?php
if (isset($_POST["save"]))
{
$name = $_POST["name"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
if (($name == '') && ($pass == '')) 
{
echo "Fields Must Be Filled...";
exit();
}
if ($name == '') {
echo "Enter Name...";
exit();
}
if ($pass == '') {
echo "Enter Password...";
exit();
}
else
{        
echo "Your name " . $name;
echo "<br/>";
echo "Your Password " . $pass;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Use javascript function to validate all fields..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a little easier approach for your POST handling. You can do a

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value )
{
   ${$key} = $value;
   //If you need to database process the data, you can put mysql_escape_string( $value );
}
```

Now, all your POSTs will be in variables with the name of the field.

After processing them for errors and more, and you wish them to be in your form element's value. You can just use the variable

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?=$email?>">
```

Or, if you use the POST

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?=$_POST['email']?>">
```

Best regards.
Jonas

Working code :-)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["save"]))
{
    //Run through all objects set in the POST array
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value )
    {
        //Set a variable named the same as the input elements name, and with the value
        ${$key} = $value;
    }
}

    $error = false;
    if( empty($name) && empty($pass) ) 
    { 
        $error = true;
        $message = "Fields must be filled...";
    }
    elseif( empty($name) )
    { 
        $error = true;
        $message = "Enter name...";
    }
    elseif( empty($pass) )
    {
        $error = true;
        $message = "Enter Password...";
    }

    if( $error == true && isset($message) )
    {
        echo $message."<br><br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Your name " . $name;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Your Password " . $pass;
    }
?>
<html><br><br>
<form method="post" action="">
Enter Name  :   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=(isset($name) ? $name : "")?>"/><br/>
Enter Password  :   <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?=(isset($pass) ? $pass : "")?>" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: dude can you please elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: @Bkay Great mate :-) Please accept answer if its working as supposed .

Comment: dude one last thing i need that if user get no error then the fields have to be blank again..

Comment: Change <?=(isset($name) ? $name : "")?> to <?=(isset($name) && $error == true ? $name : "")?>

Comment: thanks very much dude so nice of you.. accepting your answer.. enjoy more reputation ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just set the value of your input fields to match the $_POST arguments.
Your form would be..

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="">
Enter Name  :   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" /><br/>
Enter Password  :   <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $_POST['pass']; ?>" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be noteworthy that this solution, while acceptable in this case, won't work if the form is submitted to a different file

Comment: im just getting the error undefined variable..... in text boxes. :( what do i have to do now?

Comment: Matanya, why you think that? POST variables are being passed to different file too.. So putting the POST data as value to an input field wouldn't be any problem at all.

Comment: Bkay, use print_r($_POST) to check which POST variables are being passed to make sure the names are correct

Comment: this seems working fine but the problem is when form first loads it only then it shows the error messege. any idea how to prevent it?

Comment: you can set control around it.

Enter Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['save']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; ?>" /><br/>
Enter Password  :   <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['save']) ? $_POST['pass'] : ''; ?>" /><br/>

Answer (score 1):

Enter Name  :   `<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>`

would be something like this

```
<?php 

$postvalue_name = (isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : 'Fill in your name..'; 
?>

Enter Name  : <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $postvalue_name; ?>" /><br/>
```

Comment: no need for condition. He can use the `Placeholder` attr which will take effect if the value (i.e $_POST) is empty

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you. It's not about placeholder lol.